# Vector iterating forever in C

Tags: c

I am trying to use the classical pattern:

```
for (void *cur = vec_first(v); cur != NULL; cur = vec_next(v, cur))
```

Using the following function for next:

```
void *vec_next(const Vector *v, const void *prev)
{

    void *next = (char*) prev + v->elemsz;
    return next;

}
```

When cur is NULL, I imagine the vector should stop iterating. However it iterates all the way to a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why? What is wrong with this code and why doesn't it terminate?

Comment: There's likely a vec_last you should be using instead of waiting for a NULL return.

Comment: What have you tried? Debugger? Print statements of the addresses? What is the structure like and did you initialize it properly? Does the vec_add (or whatever) properly put a null after it adds a value? How do you expect to get a useful answer from your question?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger before posting the question? If yes, then what did you see as the value of `cur` changed at each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your your `Vector` implements its operations so it has `NULL` value for his last element. If that is not fullfiled it will take some corrupted memory. Maybe think about keeping the count of added elements.

Answer (score 2):

When you reach the end of the array and add v->elemsz, the result isn't NULL. It's rubbish.